# which one to use for model tuning: dask-kubernetes versus dask-yarn

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I am newbie in dask & considering using it for parallelization for ml model tuning purposes.
Should i try dask-yarn or dask-kubernetes for such requirement?

Any general ideas on where to use which of these will also be helpful for broader understanding.

Thanks

Comment: Which do you have, a kubernetes or a hadoop cluster?

Comment: I need to decide whether to use EKS OR EMR cluster. Depending on what approach might be better, I can choose :)

Answer (score 0):

Most people choose the appropriate deployment solution to match the infrastructure that they already have. This is particularly true for YARN/hadoop - you would probably only make such a cluster from scratch if you know you need it.

Surveys indicate that kubernetes is the most commonly used orchestrator for dask (not counting local, bare/ssh or HPC), and it seems to be the most common way to make clusters these days, in general. Note that you can use dask-kubernetes itself, or [dask-gateway](https://github.com/dask/dask-gateway) (which can spawn on multiple backends).

I do *not* vouch for EKS being a particularly good kubernetes implementation.